# Use latest version of installed Git on OS X

Tags: terminal, git

I'm trying to use the latest version of Git on my OS X computer, without success! When i write git --version, I see the pre-installed version 1.7.10.2. I would like to use 1.8.0 that i have also installed.

The docs says that the new version is installed in /usr/local/git, but I dont know where the version "in use" is located. I'm very unexperienced with the Terminal, but if you tell me what to write i can do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `which git` to find which version of git is used and its path.

To use the most updated version you could either call it with its full path returned by which, or create a bash alias like that:
`alias git='/usr/local/git'`

This would only be saved for current bash session. To save it for future usages, you'll have to create/modify your `~/.profile` file (where `~` is the path to your Home directory, like `/Users/lucas/`)

It's an invisible file and you won't see it in the Finder by default.
To see if such file already exists and edit it, go to your home directory :
`cd`

Then list all files, including hidden files : `ls -al` (`a` is for all files and `l` to output the list in list format, not column)

You can see in the far-right column, filenames, in which we will look for .profile file.

If you see it, open it with TextEdit from Terminal : `open .profile`

Otherwise, if it do not exists, simply open TextEdit and create a new file:

We should have something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
alias git='/usr/local/bin/git'
```

Save it as `.profile` , close your Terminal window and create a new one.

It should work ! :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me but instead of doing exactly as you said i created a .bash_profile and changed the path in vim. Now i'm finally running the latest version :) Great with ls -al also!